# Error accessing pulp from rPython

Tags: python, r, pulp

I am running on max osx 10.12.

I would like to be able to access the Python module `pulp` from within R via the `rPython` R package.  When I try:

```
library(rPython)
python.exec("import pulp")
```

I get:

```
Error in python.exec("import pulp") : 
  dlopen(/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
```

Interestingly, if I call the import command again, I get this new message:

```
Error in python.exec("import pulp") : cannot import name sparse
```

Subsequent calls to the import command continue to yield this.

I am able to import and use `pulp` just fine from within Python itself.  Also, I am able to use `rPython` to import other modules, including those installed with `pip` (which is what I used here).  Thus, this seems to be an issue specific to `pulp`, but I am not able to interpret anything very meaningful from the error message, nor can I find much useful about it via Google.